# inline specifier in a friend function declaration

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm having a question about N4842.

For 9.2.7 The inline specifier, there is

"If the inline specifier is used in a friend function declaration, that declaration shall be a definition or the function shall have previously been declared inline."

in fifth paragraph.

But no error has occurred by the following code.

```
struct X{
     friend inline void f();
};

void f(){} // no error
```

Why is not there error?
Please teach me.

Comment: You really shouldn't reference the latest draft standard when talking about the behavior of a particular compiler. You don't know which parts of the standard are changed from the one that the compiler is trying to implement. Use the version of the standard for the version of C++ you're trying to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a compiler bug, which I was able to reproduce on all big 3 compilers. Standard verbiage here is very explicit:

10.1.6/5 (latest draft):

> If the inline specifier is used in a friend function declaration, that
>   declaration shall be a definition or the function shall have
>   previously been declared inline.

4.1/1:

> The set of diagnosable rules consists of all syntactic and semantic
>   rules in this International Standard except for those rules containing
>   an explicit notation that “no diagnostic is required” or which are
>   described as resulting in “undefined behavior”.

...

> (2.2) — If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or
>   an occurrence of a construct described in this International Standard
>   as “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support
>   that construct, a conforming implementation shall issue at least one
>   diagnostic message.

Since the rule is not marked as 'no diagnostic is required', failure to provide one is a compiler bug. If you feeling strongly about it, you can file a bugreport.